# picturebox path parameter

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to add a parameter to image path.Otherwise,I'll call those images through a parameter with integer number.
For example:

```
hamlekullanici.Image = Image.FromFile(@"images\\"+hamlekullanici+".png");

Username -- > hamle 
Variable -- > integer
```

So,I want to show different images according to `hamle` number.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) to create the string for the image filename?  Something like...

```
hamlekullanici.Image = Image.FromFile(
        string.Format(@"images\{0}{1}.png", username, number);
```

...or have I misunderstood what you're trying to do?